# Probability $X$ is odd in a geometric distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have this problem:

> Let $X$ be a Geometric distribution with parameter $p = \frac1{10}$.

What is the value of $P(x\text{ is odd})$?

> What I got was $P(X = i) = pq^{i-1}$ where $p = \frac{1}{10}$ and $q = (1-p)$

Is this right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$P(\text{X is odd}) = P(X=1) + P(X=3) + P(X=5) + \ldots$$

The pmf of a geometric distribution is $q^{k-1}p$.

So $$P(\text{X is odd}) = q^{0} p + q^{2}p + q^{4} p + \ldots = p \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} q^{2k} = \frac{p}{1-q^{2}}$$

EDIT:

which equals $ \displaystyle\frac{1}{q+1}$ as pointed out by Dilip Sarwate in the comments

Comment: and $\displaystyle \frac{p}{1-q^2} = \frac{p}{(1-q)(1+q)} = \frac{1}{1+q}$ since $p = 1-q$.

Comment: How did you convert the infinite series to $1/(1-q^2)$?

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer   It's a geometric series with common ratio $q^{2}$ since $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} q^{2k} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (q^{2})^{k} $.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that if $X$ is odd then Alphonse wins the game, while if $X$ is even then Beti wins the game. It is clear that with probability $1$ one of Alphonse or Beti wins. Let $p$ be the probability A wins.

If A fails to win on the first trial, then the roles of A and B are reversed, and B has probability $p$ of winning. It follows that
$$p+\frac{9}{10}p=1.$$
Solve for $p$.